# Что такое граф сцены и глифы в qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Что такое граф сцены и глифы в qt?

Comment: Глиф - один символ шрифта (т.е. обычно одна буква). Граф сцены - такая штука, где хранятся все рисуемые объеты, организованные (обычно) в виде дерева.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat буква - частный случай. В общем смысле это единица какой-либо графики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Уж не знаю про "какой-либо графики". Я это слово слышал только применительно к рисованию текста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделенный граф сцены используется например в Qt Quick 2, который затем проходит и визуализируется через графический API, такой как OpenGL ES, OpenGL, Vulkan, Metal или Direct 3D. Использование графа сцены для графики, а не традиционных императивных систем живописи (QPainter и тому подобное) означает, что сцена, которая должна быть визуализирована, может быть сохранена между кадрами, и полный набор примитивов для визуализации известен до начала визуализации. Это открывает возможности для ряда оптимизаций, таких как пакетная визуализация для минимизации изменений состояния и отмена скрытых примитивов.

Например, пользовательский интерфейс содержит список из десяти элементов, каждый из которых имеет цвет фона, значок и текст. Используя традиционные методы рисования, это приведет к 30 вызовам рисования и аналогичному количеству изменений состояния. Граф сцены, с другой стороны, может реорганизовать примитивы для визуализации так, чтобы все фоны были нарисованы в одном вызове, затем все значки, затем весь текст, уменьшая общее количество вызовов рисования только до 3. Такое пакетирование и снижение изменения состояния может значительно повысить производительность некоторых аппаратных средств.

О "глифах" слышу впервые, возможно вы неправильно указали название)

Comment: глиф - это "картинка" символов текста. Весь этот текст вы видите лишь потому, что браузер правильно нарисовал глифы. )))
В QML добавлением текстовых узлов в сцену занимается приватный QQuickTextNode (и тамошний обвяз): https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquicktextnode.cpp.html#_ZN14QQuickTextNode9addGlyphsERK7QPointFRK9QGlyphRunRK6QColorN10QQuickText9TextStyleES8_P7QSGNode